# php finding amount of square numbers in interval

Tags: php, math

So I want to find all square numbers in $A and $B (including interval borders); here the output should be 3 because there are 3 square numbers (integer) between those numbers which are: 4 = 2^2, 9 = 3^2 and 16 = 4^2

```
function solution($A, $B) {
  $A = 4;
  $B = 17;

  for($i=$A; $i<=$B; $i++) {
    $sqrt = sqrt($i);
    if (strpos($sqrt, '.') !== false) {
      $sqrt = intval($sqrt);
      print $sqrt;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check **[demo here](https://eval.in/787601)**

```
range(ceil(sqrt($A)), floor(sqrt($B)));
```